# How to configure and authenticate users again active directory using OKTA?

Tags: .net, active-directory, okta, okta-api

How to configure and authenticate users again active directory using OKTA. Can you please mention the steps and sample example for same.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow!  Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

The [AD Agent guide](https://support.okta.com/help/articles/Knowledge_Article/28774118-Installing-and-Configuring-the-Active-Directory-Agent) describes how to install and configure the AD Agent.  Once this is completed, you can use the APIs at http://developer.okta.com to authenticate the user.